# Binary vs 4-PAM PSD

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, power-spectral-density, signal-power

I'm struggling to understand how you would form an expression for the PSD of a 4-PAM signal which is using rectangular pulse shaping.  I understand for binary the likelihood of +/1 is equal so the auto-correlation is trivial. What would the expression look like for 4-PAM?

Thanks

Comment: See section 15.4 of A. Lapidoth's book "A foundation in digital communication", available here: https://www.afidc.ethz.ch/A_Foundation_in_Digital_Communication/Home.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power Spectral Density of Digital Modulations](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45769/power-spectral-density-of-digital-modulations)