# The difference about QPSK, BPSK and 16-QAM in spectrum

Tags: matlab, qpsk, bpsk

What is the difference about QPSK, BPSK and 16-QAM in spectrum? I just simulated all three, but I can't see the difference clearly.

Comment: You can't see the difference clearly because maybe there _is_ no difference.  Absent any information about data rates, available bandwidth, etc, and _how_ you "simulated" the spectra, your question is unanswerable. I am voting to close this question.

Comment: I think Dilip really hits the point: assume your result is correct, i.e. the spectra are identical. Now go back to your signals textbook and figure out why! (That's what the learning experience probably is that this assignment was designed to give.)

Comment: If you need help finding a derivation: I'm currently on my phone so I'm bound to memory and what I have found in my other answers here, but Proakis' "Digital Communications", 3rd ed., eq. 4-4-17 should be what you need.

Comment: It's answering a different question, but the answer did match your question very well:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Power Spectral Density of Digital Modulations](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45769/power-spectral-density-of-digital-modulations)